# Что за рекурсивное добавление файлов в очередь (filezilla)?

Tags: сервер, ftp, рекурсия, веб-сервер

Скачиваю проект по фтп с помощью FileZilla.
Впервые столкнулся с подобным казусом:
Что нужно скачать (и размер): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что скачало (и размер) и всё еще качает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратил внимание на это (при отмене прекращается загрузка): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Это означает что FileZilla рекурсивно обходит папки, и добавляет их содержимое в очередь загрузки.

В поле "общий размер" на сервере, отображается суммарный объём файлов которе находятся в текущей директории, без учета файлов которые находятся в дочерних директориях. Объём всех данных вместе с директориями, поддиректориями, подподдиректориями... может быть значительно больше того что указывает FileZilla.